# How do you get full support of zen coding in NetBeans 6.9?

Tags: html, netbeans, ide, emmet

I'm using NetBeans 6.9 with the [Zen Coding plugin](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/).

I was wondering if there is a way to get the selector support working in NetBeans.

Currently typing this:

```
ul#my-list>li*3>a
```

Does ***not*** produce this:

```
<ul id="my-list">
 <li><a href=""></a></li>
 <li><a href=""></a></li>
 <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know yet, there is full support Zen Coding for NetBeans. lorenzos did a great job check it out if you interested https://github.com/lorenzos/ZenCodingNetBeansPlugin

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing this is a new project?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is available on Netbeans yet. Even though there is a [download for Netbeans](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=NetBeans.Zen.HTML.1.2.zip) in the [Zen Coding repository](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/), it really just proivdes a list of code templates and macros to speed up coding HTML in Netbeans. [This site](http://vimeo.com/9117346) provides a nice video tutorial on how to install and use this source in Netbeans on Windows.

Until someone volunteers to write a proper plugin for Netbeans, you won't get the full Zen coding capability on Netbeans. Why don't you use another editor, such as Notepad++ (Windows)?

Comment: I use Zen Coding with NPP. But at work I have to use netbeans.

Comment: Work is always a bit more trickier...especially if you are on an SOE.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to click on given below link

[Zen coding for netbeans](https://github.com/lorenzos/ZenCodingNetBeansPlugin#readme)

And download  .nbm file

after that open your netbeans IDE

go "tool menu" and select "plugins" and click on "Add plugins"

Select downloaded(.nbm) file from your folder

And click on install button which is given below

After installation restart your netbeans IDE and you will see Z symbol on your tool bar menu

type html:5 and click on Z symbol or press (ctrl+alt+N) .